# How to parse a word enclosed in quotes in C?

Tags: c, string, mac-address

I need to parse mac address from a string like `"mac" : "11:22:33:44:55:66"` using c.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main() {
    char str[50] = "\"mac\" : \"11:22:33:44:55:66\"";
    char second_string[20];
    sscanf(str, "what should come here?", second_string);
    printf("%s\n", second_string);
}
```

My output should be:

> 11:22:33:44:55:66

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`scanf` family of functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) do *simple* pattern matching. Therefore you can do something like

```
sscanf(str, "\"mac\" : \"%[^\"]\"", second_string);
```

The `"%[^"` format matches anything *except* the characters before the closing `"]"`.

---

For a more generic solution, you could find the separating `':'` (for example with [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr)) and only parse the last part of the string (after the `':'`).

To be even more generic skip the colon and all white-space (with a loop and [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)), which will leave you with only `"\"11:22:33:44:55:66\""` to parse. And that can be done using the `"%[^"` format as shown above.

Comment: Thanks its working but if "mac" wont be same in all cases need generic solution

Comment: @Aravind Updated